# Cannot restore and dump database PostgreSQL with Ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

The part of code that gives me an error is:

```
- name: import database jira64_20180626.dump.tar.gz
  postgresql_db:
    name: jira64_20180626.dump.gz
    login_user: jira
    login_password: jira_pwd
    state: restore
    target: /var/lib/pgsql/jira64_20180626.dump.tar.gz
```

The error is:

> fatal: [node-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "cmd: ****", "msg": "\ngzip: stdout: Broken pipe\n", "rc": 1, "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: looks like you end up with below bug:: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20196

Comment: Thanks, I just read the contents of the link .. They should have solved this issue but then why does it appear even if Ansible is updated?

Comment: Its still open. You can check the status on the top

Comment: @Aless1995 I think the problem is the `name` parameter , as in documentation, **name** is _"Name of the database to add or remove"_.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_db_module.html

Answer (score 0):

The name seems incorrect & the correct code would be as:

```
- name: import database jira64_20180626.dump.tar.gz
  postgresql_db:
    name: name of the db which you want to restore
    login_user: jira
    login_password: jira_pwd
    state: restore
    target: /TheDUMPfilepath/jira64_20180626.dump.tar.gz
```

If this is not working The Ansible Doc [click here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_db_module.html) says restore format as below:

The format of the backup will be detected based on the target name.
Supported compression formats for dump and restore include .bz2, .gz and .xz
Supported formats for dump and restore include .sql and .tar

For example as below:

```
- name: Dump  existing database
  postgresql_db:
    name: acme
    state: dump
    target: /tmp/acme.sql
```